# Grouping months data into year

Tags: r

My data frame looks somewhat like this

```
1976 January     250
1976 February    350
1976 March       230
1976 April       255
```

This goes up to 2007

I want to aggregate and find the mean of the data per year. I want to create a variable that would contain a table of data mean by each year. So that it looks like

```
1976      mean of all 1976 months
1977      mean of all 1976 months
1978      mean of all 1976 months
1979      mean of all 1976 months
```

and so on

How can I do it?

The data frame is "data" and the first column is "year"

```
variable_name <- aggregate(x=data$secondcolumn_name, by=list(data$Year),  FUN="mean")
```

But it is not getting aggregated. I think since the column "year" has characters is the problem.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not share sample data as images, rather look at how to [make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Also you may share your expected output and the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Hi, I have changed the question. Can you remove the "closed" tag please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `Year` column has always the same form that in the image and its class is `character`, the dataframe is called `data` and the name of the second column is `second_column_name` (to abbreviate the name in the image), then you can do:

```r
library(dplyr)
data %>%
    group_by(substr(Year,1,4)) %>%
    summarise(avg = mean(second_column_name))
```

Or using `mutate` instead of `summarise` if you want to preserve the monthly data.

Comment: Hi, I tried the codes. It did group the first column by year however the avg is for some reason coming the same for all the years.

Comment: Without a reproducible example I cannot test it.